# Shell shortcuts to folders in Windows

Tags: windows, bash, shell, powershell, cmd

I'm learning Vagrant and Virtualbox, Now to add a line to my hosts file in a (windows)

```
echo "test" >> c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts
```

But i'm wondering **if i can make a Shortcut to c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts** that i can use in any shell from everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You might create an environment variable:

```
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Youralias','c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts','Machine)
```

and then access it using

```
$env:YourAlias
```

from PowerShell... If you want to access it from CMD

```
%Youralias%
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so there isn't a nice way like mac can do it? just using alias test="blabla" and then running "test" ?

Comment: Well, you said 'any' shell. If you want to use only PowerShell; in fact there is set alias='that path' but I assumed you want to access it from 'cmd' shell as well. Is that not the case?

Comment: Well i'm currently using the Git Bash in combination with ConEmu for some more advanced options regarding how the Git Bash looks

Comment: Usually aliases are specific to their environment. I mean you might even possibly use git config --global alias.MyAlias='c:/Windows/system2/drivers/etc/hosts' ?

Comment: Good idea! But it's giving me an error
error: invalid key: alias.TestAlias=c:/windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: I am not too familiar with the exact environment but within GitBash you do have access to environment variables with 'env' command. So if you use the command above to set a variable(alias) you can get possibly get to with 'env | grep -i YouAlias'

Comment: btw for git alias, there is no '=' sign there... it config --global alias.mytestalias 'c:/...'

Answer (score -1):

## Easier solution using a **.bash_profile** file

In your home folder (windows) you can make a .bash_profile file and specify aliases.
Go to your home folder

```
cd ~
```

make a .bash_profile file and open it in vim or any other editor

```
touch .bash_profile && vim .bash_profile
```

add a new alias by adding the following line

```
alias testfolder="cd /c/testfolder"
```

save and close your editor.

#### Explanation someone?

For some reason it only works after i run the following command

```
source .bash_profile
```